# Python3 scripts in "venv" imports matplotlib from Python2.7 rather Python3 site packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, python-venv

I’m having a deployment problem/Import Error with Python3 scripts that are running inside “venv” virtual env, one of the scripts that imports “matplotlib” & “numpy” seems to be incorrectly referring to python2.7 site packages rather than python3 site-packages.

Background: The project was to migrate some Python2 scripts running on RHEL7 , to Python3 scripts and run them on RHEL8.

However other teams have fallen behind and they wanted Python3 scripts to be moved back to the legacy RHEL7 environment & work alongside other the old Python2 legacy scripts.

Because the base OS RHEL7 has both Python2.7 and Python3.6.8 , I created a “venv” and installed all the required packages inside “venv” via PIP.

**Problem:** One of the Python3 scripts inside “venv” keeps importing "matplotlib" & "numpy" from Python2.7 site packages incorrectly, rather than the "matplotlib" & "numpy" from Python3 site packages.

**1)    Note the Python3 script is self-contained and does not call any Python2 scripts.**

**2)    I explicitly created “venv” pointing to Python3:**

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 new_py3_env
```

3. Furthermore, I appended & inserted required libraries specifically at the top of the script:

```py
sys.path.insert(2,python3_base_path.get_base_path()+'/python3_branchs/mickey-python3/mickey_LOCAL/new_py3_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages')
sys.path.insert(3,python3_base_path.get_base_path()+'/python3_branchs/mickey-python3/mickey_LOCAL/new_py3_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

**4)    Check the Python3 version in “venv” shows correct Python3 version:**
Python 3.6.8

**5) matplotlib & numpy are installed via pip3 in venv.**

**pip3 list shows:**
numpy                        1.9.2
matplotlib                   1.3.1

**However, after running the script I still get:**

```
[new_py3_env] buster@mickeyrh7python:/home/buster/mickey/python3_branchs/mickey-python3/mickey_LOCAL:<tcsh-165> python3 /home/buster/mickey/python3_branchs/mickey-python3/mickey_LOCAL/python-from-OPS/mickey/venue/analysis/systems/tools/bin/backup_process.py ~/python-from-OPS/mickey/test/lut_sync/backup_process_python3_test_case_1_current_output.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/buster/mickey/python3_branchs/mickey-python3/mickey_LOCAL/python-from-OPS/mickey/venue/analysis/systems/tools/bin/backup_process.py", line 28, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/opt/shameless/pos/cse/1.6/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 156, in <module>
    from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like
  File "/opt/shameless/pos/cse/1.6/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 28, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/opt/shameless/pos/cse/1.6/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 170, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/opt/shameless/pos/cse/1.6/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/opt/shameless/pos/cse/1.6/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/opt/shameless/pos/cse/1.6/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/opt/shameless/pos/cse/1.6/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_multiarray)
```

How can I configure "venv" or Python3 to import Python3-installed packages rather than referring to Python2.7 versions?

Appreciated

Comment: Is `PYTHONPATH` set in your environment?

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you , I had set PYTHON_PATH instead PYTHONPATH. Resolved.

Comment: "Furthermore, I appended & inserted required libraries specifically at the top of the script:" - I notice you're inserting them not at the front. Did you try to check what the prior entries in `sys.path` were? That probably would have hinted at the `PYTHONPATH` configuration issue.